# How would the case of the key in request.form.get('kEy') be handled in all variations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

How would an external cURL request to a python 3 endpoint where one of the form parameters is "key" be able to handle all case variations of the spelling of "key" without having to check for:

```
request.form.get('key')
request.form.get('Key')
request.form.get('kEy')
request.form.get('keY')
request.form.get('KEy')
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much flask specific knowledge, but trying to answer your question in Python, I would try something like the following

```
def iget(dictionary, key):
    ''' Case insensitive get '''
    lower_key = key.lower()
    for key in dictionary:
        if key.lower() == lower_key:
            return dictionary[key]


# key = 'key' or 'Key' or ... 
iget(request.form, key)
```